# MoveIt moveit::core::RobotModel::RobotModel

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

I can not create a RobotModelConstPtr. I need this to create a RobotState (http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_core/html/classmoveit_1_1core_1_1RobotState.html#ac5944765b49ee074030c01010af36c07).

A part of my Code:
// Construct a kinematic model
const RobotModelConstPtr kinematic_model; //need it later for RobotState
robot_model::RobotModel kinematic_model = (RDFLoader.getURDF(), RDFLoader.getSRDF());

The error is " 'RobotModelConstPtr' does not name a type".

This is a link to my hole code (https://www.dropbox.com/s/rko84pkkiigug9j/inv_node_end.cpp?dl=0).

It would be perfect if someone can help me out.

Thanks

The whole code:

```
 #include <ros/ros.h>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <urdf/model.h>

// MoveIt!
 #include <moveit/robot_model/robot_model.h>
 #include <moveit/robot_state/robot_state.h>
 #include <moveit/rdf_loader/rdf_loader.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "inv_node");
 
  ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);

  spinner.start();

  ros::NodeHandle nh;


// Convert urdf file in a string

  std::ifstream u("youbot_arm.urdf");

  std::stringstream su;

  su << u.rdbuf();


// upload the urdf to the parameter server

  nh.setParam("robot_description", su.str());


// Convert srdf file in a string

  std::ifstream s("youbot.srdf");

  std::stringstream ss;

  ss << s.rdbuf();


// upload the srdf to the parameter server

  nh.setParam("robot_description_semantic", ss.str());


// Initialize the robot model

  rdf_loader::RDFLoader RDFLoader(su.str(), ss.str()); 


// Construct a kinematic model

  const RobotModelConstPtr kinematic_model; //need it later for RobotState

  robot_model::RobotModel kinematic_model = (RDFLoader.getURDF(), RDFLoader.getSRDF());

  ROS_INFO("Model frame: %s", kinematic_model->getModelFrame().c_str());


// RobotStat that maintains the configuration

  robot_state::RobotStatePtr kinematic_state(new robot_state::RobotState(RobotModel);

  kinemati_state->setToDefaultValues();


// choose JointGroup

  const robot_state::JointModelGroup* joint_model_group = RobotModel.getJointModelGroup("arm_1");


// Forward Kinematics

  kinematic_state->setToRandomPositions(joint_model_group);

  const Eigen::Affine3d &end_effector_state = kinematic_state->getGlobalLinkTransform("arm_link_0");


/* Print end-effector pose. Remember that this is in the model frame */

  ROS_INFO_STREAM("Translation: " << end_effector_state.translation());

  ROS_INFO_STREAM("Rotation: " << end_effector_state.rotation());

  ros::shutdown();

  return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292048/moveit-moveit::core::robotmodel::robotmodel/) by [JonasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/34613/jonasg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-05-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-05-23**:
Can you please update your question with a copy and paste of your code? That way the question is self-contained.

**Comment by [JonasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/34613/jonasg/) on 2018-05-23**:
I have updated my question. I hope the formatation is good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like RobotModelConstPrt is declared in http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_core/html/robot__model_8h_source.html by `MOVEIT_CLASS_FORWARD(RobotModel);` .

This is in the `moveit::core` namespace, so the fully qualified type name would be `moveit::core::RobotModelConstPtr`

Instead of:

```
const RobotModelConstPtr kinematic_model; //need it later for RobotState
```

Try:

```
const moveit::core::RobotModelConstPtr kinematic_model; //need it later for RobotState
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JonasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/34613/jonasg/) on 2018-06-06**:
@ahendrix Do you have experience by using KDL PLugins for computing inverse kinematics?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-06-06**:
Nope. I don't know anything about MoveIt, I'm just good at reading and interpreting software documentation.

**Comment by [saztyga](https://answers.ros.org/users/54402/saztyga/) on 2020-08-31**:
@ahendrix   Sir can you suggest me any tutorial where i can learn how to interpreter c++ documantation